# Angular tests fails with ng e2e but pass with protractor conf.js

Tags: angular, testing, automation, jasmine, e2e-testing

while working on test automation for angular apps, i faced a problem that whenever I try to run the test suit with angular command `ng e2e` all the tests fail. The same tests get passed with protractor command `protractor conf.js`. I want to ask the reason for this weird behavior. The spec is provided.
Thanks

```js
import { AddMemberClass } from '../../pages/add-member/add-member.page';
import { LoginPage } from '../../pages/login/login.page';
import { browser, promise, by } from 'protractor';


fdescribe('Add Member as Admin',()=>{

    let addMemeber: AddMemberClass;
    let login : LoginPage;

    beforeAll(()=>{
        login = new LoginPage();
        addMemeber = new AddMemberClass();
        return new Promise((resolve)=>{
            login.navigateTo().then(()=>{
                login.getEmailInput().sendKeys('something@gmail.com');
                login.getPasswordInput().sendKeys('13235');
                login.getLoginButton().click().then(()=>{
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('organization').then(()=>{
                            resolve();
                            });
                    },30000);
                });
            });
        });    
    }); 
    
    it('should login successfully', ()=>{
        return addMemeber.getMemberMenu().click().then(()=>{
            console.log('test1');
            return addMemeber.getAddMemberSubMenu().click().then(()=>{
                 console.log('inside test 1');
                return  new Promise((resolve)=>{
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('directregistration').then(()=>{
                        resolve();
                        });
                    },30000)
                })
            })
        })
        
    });    
   
    it('should check member Menu on main page',()=>{
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
           setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log('Inside test 2 timeout');
                expect(addMemeber.getMemberMenu().isPresent()).toBe(true);
                resolve();
            },5000)    
        });     
    });

  
    })

});
```

Comment: That would be great if you provide us with exact error message

Comment: the issue is your setTimeout and Promises. That's not how it's supposed to be done :)

Comment: @LuninRoman The error is jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT

Comment: @PierreDuc can you explain it a bit more. Will be thankful

Comment: @Analyst I suggest you to have a look at https://angular.io/guide/testing. You should use `async`. You get the error because the default timeout is a lot less than the 30 seconds you want your test to wait for.

Comment: while using `protractor conf.js` and running only this specific suit, all tests are passed while running all test suites i.e. describe block. only this suit fails and all others are passed (successful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was facing is with `ng e2e` it first serves the app and then run e2e test cases. With running the command protractor conf.js, it was not served, creating issue and failing all test cases